# Movable control and form boundaries

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on simple winform application where I would like to make a picture (box) movable within the main form. However I would like to ensure that the picture cant be moved across the borders. The main form itself should stay resizable.

The image itself has a resolution of 200x200. I have set the border style of the parent picture box to 'FixedSingle' which results in total picture box control dimensions of 202x202.

However I am still able to move the picture box slightly "out" of the winform. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

```
private Point _MouseDownLocation;
private Size _FormSize; 

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) => this._FormSize = Size;

private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) => this._FormSize = ((Form)sender).Size;

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        _MouseDownLocation = e.Location;    
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        int newX = e.X + pictureBox1.Left - _MouseDownLocation.X;
        int newY = e.Y + pictureBox1.Top - _MouseDownLocation.Y;

        int rightBoundary = _FormSize.Width - pictureBox1.Width;
        int bottomBoundary = _FormSize.Height - pictureBox1.Height - statusStrip1.Height; 

        if (newX <= rightBoundary && newX >= 0 && newY <= bottomBoundary && newY >= 0)
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(newX, newY);                     
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably have an `else` there that if one of those is exceeded it sets it to the maximum value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem of the code is because of using the `Size` property of the `Form`.

Instead of using `Size` of the form, you should use [`ClientSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9278sfx2(v=vs.110).aspx) of the form. 
Client size returns the size of client area of the form (which doesn't include title-bar and borders), while size returns size of the whole form, including non-client area.

> The size of the client area of the form is the size of the form
>   excluding the borders and the title bar. The client area of a form is
>   the area within a form where controls can be placed. You can use this
>   property to get the proper dimensions when performing graphics
>   operations or when sizing and positioning controls on the form. To get
>   the size of the entire form, use the Size property or use the
>   individual properties Height and Width.

**Note**

- You don't need to keep size in a field, so remove `Load` and `Resize` event handlers and just use `this.ClientSize` wherever you need.
- When assigning the new location for the moving control, use separate criteria for detecting edge collision. Now if the control collides with top edge, you are also preventing move to left and right!

Comment: Still the question remains why 'Size' doesnt really match the outter borders of the form... strange

Answer (score 1):

You should evaluate the limits separately and limit them instead of all as one `if` statement:

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            int newX = e.X + pictureBox1.Left - _MouseDownLocation.X;
            int newY = e.Y + pictureBox1.Top - _MouseDownLocation.Y;

            int rightBoundary = ClientSize.Width - pictureBox1.Width;
            int bottomBoundary = ClientSize.Height - pictureBox1.Height - statusStrip1.Height;

            if (newX > rightBoundary)
                newX = rightBoundary;
            else if (newX < 0)
                newX = 0;

            if (newY > bottomBoundary)
                newY = bottomBoundary;
            else if (newY < 0)
                newY = 0;

            pictureBox1_MouseMove.Location = new Point(newX, newY);
        }
    }
```

This can probably be shortened with some more creative coding, but you should get the point. If the boundary is outside the limits, set it at the closest limit. This way if you drag to the bottom the picture will stop moving in the Y direction while still be able to move in the X direction.

The other issue is, as the other answer suggested, the use of `ClientSize` versus `Size`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your very helpful replies. This now works like a charm. However I still had to subtract the height of statusstrip to get the correct y-axis.

```
private Point _MouseDownLocation;

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        _MouseDownLocation = e.Location; 
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        int newX = e.X + pictureBox1.Left - _MouseDownLocation.X;
        int newY = e.Y + pictureBox1.Top - _MouseDownLocation.Y;

        int rightBoundary = this.ClientSize.Width - pictureBox1.Width;
        int bottomBoundary = this.ClientSize.Height - pictureBox1.Height - statusStrip1.Height;

        if (newX > rightBoundary)
            newX = rightBoundary;
        else if (newX < 0)
            newX = 0;

        if (newY > bottomBoundary)
            newY = bottomBoundary;
        else if (newY < 0)
            newY = 0; 

        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(newX, newY);
    }
}
```

I am not sure if I should create a new SO question for this, but as it is a follow up question I am adding it here:

When making the main form smaller and pulling the borders over the content/Picture box it can get into an non-reachable area. I as a user would expect that the content moves while the form gets resized.

How can I prevent this?

[image]